Finding the coordinate of four points of imaginary intersecting lines which passes through end points of two intersecting lines
image
I want to find the coordinates of the points A,B,C,D where two imaginary lines intersect each other, where this imaginary lines passes through the end points of the two lines L1 and L2, the imaginary lines AB and DC are parallel to line L2 and the imaginary lines AD and BC are parallel to line L1. This diagram is an example, so coordinate points P(6,6), Q(4,3), R(2,2), S(3,5) so how would I find the coordinates of point A, B, C, D. There might be other scenario like line L2 might longer and line L1 might be shorter and the angle of it may be different compared to the image shown. What should be logic to find the coordinates

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community i want to find the coordinates of points A,B,C,D, so how would i find those

i have attached an image in the start of the body
